# How can I reduce the size of my boxes and keep them centered and responsive?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 box square, there is content inside each box.
My boxes are centered and responsive, but they are very big.
I want to reduce the size of the boxes and make them small just like the blue boxes in this picture :[image]

My problem is that when I lower `width: 30%;` and `padding-bottom : 30%;` they are not centered/responsive anymore..
Here is my code:

```css
           @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);  /* <-- Just for the demo, Yes I like pretty fonts... */

            .square {
                float:left;
                position: relative;
                width: 30%;
                padding-bottom : 30%; /* = width for a 1:1 aspect ratio */
                margin:1.66%;
                background-color:#1E1E1E;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            .content {
                position:absolute;
                height:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
                width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
                padding: 5%;
                
            }
            .table{
                display:table;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .table-cell{
                display:table-cell;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            /*  For list */
            ul{
                text-align:left;
                margin:5% 0 0;
                padding:0;
                list-style-position:inside;
            }
            li{
                margin: 0 0 0 5%;
                padding:0;
            }


 
            /*  following just for the demo */


            body {
                font-size:20px;
                font-family: 'Lato',verdana, sans-serif;
                color: #fff;
                text-align:center;
                background:#ECECEC;
            }
            p{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                text-align:left;
            }

            .numbers{
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:100px;
            }

            #bottom {
                clear:both;
                margin:0 1.66%;
                width:89.68%;
                padding: 3.5%;
                background-color:#1E1E1E;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #bottom p{
                text-align:center;
                line-height:2em;
            }
            #bottom a{
                color: #000;
                text-decoration:none;
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding:10px 20px 12px;
                line-height:70px;
                background:#ccc;
                
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            #bottom a:hover{
                background:#ECECEC;
                border:1px solid #fff;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <p>
                            lorem ipsup iefzioe ezpfpzefzp oezfjzoefj ^ze f zefezf zefzefef    zefzefze
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <ul>
                            This demo shows you can center multiple types of content :
                            <li>Text</li>
                            <li>Images</li>
                            <li>Lists</li>
                            <li>... (you can also do it with forms)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <ul>
                            This demo shows you can center multiple types of content :
                            <li>Text</li>
                            <li>Images</li>
                            <li>Lists</li>
                            <li>... (you can also do it with forms)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The first rule of centering is "Don't use `float`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead of floats to center responsive content.

For example, `justify-content: space-evenly` evenly distributes free space between and around the elements.

```css
           @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900);  /* <-- Just for the demo, Yes I like pretty fonts... */

            .wrapper {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
            }

            .square {
                position: relative;
                width: 20%;
                padding-bottom : 20%;
                margin:1.66%;
                background-color:#1E1E1E;
                overflow:hidden;
            }

            .content {
                position:absolute;
                height:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
                width:90%; /* = 100% - 2*5% padding */
                padding: 5%;
                
            }
            .table{
                display:table;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .table-cell{
                display:table-cell;
                vertical-align:middle;
            }
            /*  For list */
            ul{
                text-align:left;
                margin:5% 0 0;
                padding:0;
                list-style-position:inside;
            }
            li{
                margin: 0 0 0 5%;
                padding:0;
            }


 
            /*  following just for the demo */


            body {
                font-size:20px;
                font-family: 'Lato',verdana, sans-serif;
                color: #fff;
                text-align:center;
                background:#ECECEC;
            }
            p{
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                text-align:left;
            }

            .numbers{
                font-weight:900;
                font-size:100px;
            }

            #bottom {
                clear:both;
                margin:0 1.66%;
                width:89.68%;
                padding: 3.5%;
                background-color:#1E1E1E;
                color: #fff;
            }
            #bottom p{
                text-align:center;
                line-height:2em;
            }
            #bottom a{
                color: #000;
                text-decoration:none;
                border:1px solid #000;
                padding:10px 20px 12px;
                line-height:70px;
                background:#ccc;
                
                -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

            #bottom a:hover{
                background:#ECECEC;
                border:1px solid #fff;
            }
```

```html
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <p>
                            lorem ipsup iefzioe ezpfpzefzp oezfjzoefj ^ze f zefezf zefzefef    zefzefze
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <ul>
                            This demo shows you can center multiple types of content :
                            <li>Text</li>
                            <li>Images</li>
                            <li>Lists</li>
                            <li>... (you can also do it with forms)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="square">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <ul>
                            This demo shows you can center multiple types of content :
                            <li>Text</li>
                            <li>Images</li>
                            <li>Lists</li>
                            <li>... (you can also do it with forms)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use flex-box
realy this link usefull for you :
[justify-content](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp)